# I wanted to display an alert after a form was submitted, PHP, JAVASCRIPT, HTML, AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I wanted it when the form was sent to the bank it gave an alert with something like "Your message was sent", otherwise it looks like "Error sending your message". The problem is that the code I am using it is not showing the alerts but it is indicating in the corner of screen "1".

```
<?php 


    if(!empty($_FILES['uploaded_file'])){
        $username = 'root';
        $password = '';
        $connection = new PDO( 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nise', $username );

        $query = "INSERT INTO denuncia (descricao, imagem, id_usuario, qual_descricao,id_bloco, id_denuncia_oque) 
              VALUES (:descricao, :imagem, :id_usuario, :qual_descricao, :id_bloco, :id_denuncia_oque)";

        $statement = $connection->prepare($query);





        $path = "img_denuncia/";
        $path = $path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
        if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $path))



        $valores = array();
        $valores[':descricao'] = $_POST['descricao_denuncia'];
        $valores[':imagem'] = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
        $valores[':id_usuario'] = 2;
        $valores[':qual_descricao'] = $_POST['qual_descricao'];
        $valores[':id_bloco'] = $_POST['bloco_denuncia'];
        $valores[':id_denuncia_oque'] = $_POST['id_denuncia_oque'];



    if( $result = $statement->execute($valores))
        {
         echo 1; // dados enviados com sucesso
        }
        else
        {
        // na verdade o else não é necessário mas se preferir pode colocar
         echo 0; // erro ao tentar enviar dados 
        }
}
?>
```

Here is the ajax. ---- It's the first time I'm using AJAX, if possible you could tell me why it's not working, and I've been wrong.

```
<script>



 $('#form').submit(function() {
    $.ajax({ 
        data: $(this).serialize(), 
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url:"http://localhost/projeto/aluno.php",
        success: function(retorno) {
               if(retorno==1)
              {
                alert("Formulário enviado com seucesso");
              }
               else
              {
                alert("erro ao enviar formulário");
              }
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
</script>
```

Here is my form

```
  <form id="caixa" class="center-block row col-xl-6" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formulario"  method="POST" action="aluno.php">
    <br>
      <div class="row p-0 no-margin col-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-12" >
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sel1">Bloco:</label>
          <select class="form-control " name="bloco_denuncia" id="bloco" required="required" placeholder="ex: Bloco 3" >
            <option value="" disabled selected>Ex: Computação</option>
            <option value="1">Bloco - Computação</option>
            <option value="2">Bloco - Mecânica</option>
            <option value="3">Bloco - Química</option>
            <option value="4">Bloco - Administrativo</option>
            <option value="5">Biblioteca </option>
            <option value="6">Ginásio </option>
            <option value="7">Auditório</option>
            <option value="0">Outros</option>
          </select>
          </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label for="sel1">O que:</label>
          <select select="required" class="form-control" name="id_denuncia_oque" id="sel1" required="required" >
            <option value="" disabled selected>Ex: Laboratório</option>
            <option value="1">Sala</option>
            <option value="2">Banheiro(Térreo)</option>
            <option value="3">Banheiro(Superior)</option>
            <option value="4">Laboratório</option>
            <option value="5">Coordenação</option>
            <option value="6">Gabinete</option>
            <option value="7">Telecom</option>
            <option value="8">Outros</option>

          </select>
          </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="usr">Qual:</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" name="qual_descricao" placeholder="ex: ar-condicionado " required="required" >
            </div>

      </div>
       <textarea  id="form-control"class="noresize  col-12 col-sm-12 mb-12 col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-12 " name="descricao_denuncia" placeholder="Faça sua denúncia aqui... " id="denuncia" rows="13" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
       </textarea>

       <br>
       <div class="row p-0 no-margin col-12 col-sm-12  col-md-12 col-lg-10 col-xl-12">  
            <div class="botao p-0 no-margin col-6 col-sm-6 mb-3 col-md-6 col-lg-2 col-xl-10">
           <label class="file-upload btn btn-primary">
                Escolha o arquivo... <input  type="file" name="uploaded_file"/ accept="image/*">
            </label>  
           <small class="form-text text-muted">As suas mensagens não serão totalmente anônimas.</small>
            </div>
          <div class="botao p-0 no-margin col-6 col-sm-6 mb-3 col-md-6 col-lg-10 col-xl-2 text-right ">
               <input id="b_enviar" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Enviar" name="enviar"/>
          </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <br>
    <!--Fim da caixa-->
```

If you have a javascript solution you can send it to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The id on your jquery selector is #form but **it should be #caixa**, as you declared that on your form element that id=caixa and not id=form.

Also add **e inside the function parameter**, then **e.preventDefault inside the function**. preventDefault() will stop the form from actually submitting and avoid navigating to the action page.

Also **put your script tag at the end of the body tag**, to make sure that the target element has been loaded.

Try this;

```
$('#caixa').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var formData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({ 
        data: formData, 
        type: "post",
        url:"http://localhost/projeto/aluno.php",
        success: function(retorno) {
              if(retorno=='1' || retorno==1)
              {
                alert("Formulário enviado com seucesso");
              }
               else
              {
                alert("erro ao enviar formulário");
              }
        }
    });
    return false; 
});
```

Comment: If I may add to this answer a bit... I'm pretty sure there will be an issue with `$(this)` scope within the Ajax... I would assign the form values to a variable before the Ajax function:  `var formData = $(this).serialize();` then in the ajax, `data: formData,`. -- And you know the request type here... Just do `type: "post",`

Comment: Continues the same thing is shown in the corner of screen "1" that say it worked, but does not appear the alerts

Comment: Louys Patrice Bessette, Could you show me how it would look?

Comment: Updated answer to accommodate @Louys suggestion.

Comment: @PauloVictor: In the success callback, console log the returned result : `console.log("--"+retorno+"--");` and look if there is some other characters or spaces echoed.

Comment: has not changed anything yet, I've already got all your suggestions

Comment: The only thing that is shown is the result "1" on the left side of the screen.

Comment: Could it be that something from php would be wrong?

Comment: Try put your script tag at the end of the body tag, to make sure that all the other elements have loaded.

Comment: Or put the function between `$(document).ready(function(){` and `});` [Documentation for more about the ready handler](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)